# How can I make a mesh copy the same shape of another mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I know I have already asked a similar question before, but I just can't seem to achieve the result in such a perfect way.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a way that I could have the green mesh transform its shape to be exactly like the shape of the grey mesh without losing any data or quality all around.

As you can see on the picture, the green mesh is deformed and I want to be the same shape as the grey one without effecting the quality of it.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried Duplicating it?

Comment: You need to explain how you want them to be similar and how you want them to be different. For parts that are identical, simply duplicate the object with ALT-D to make another instance of the same mesh.

Comment: Shift D to make real duplicate. Alt D to duplicate an instance (meaning if you edit the mesh, the effect is going to show up in the instanced mesh too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your best option in this case is mesh-align-plus, and modify it according to your needs, I do not understand much of your question but I try to deduce with risk to make a mistake, but this surely fits your problem

[image: Vertex align]
[image: Object align]